# Does Windows 10 use 1 or 2 partitions for system files and user data?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, filesystems, boot-partition

I was wondering if Windows uses a separate partition for system files and another for personal files like Linux does?

Comment: Note that Linux does not necessarily use separate partitions either. That's configurable, and some Linux distros default to a single partition.

Comment: @Dai I'm not saying that you are the one to blame, Microsoft surely is. But... backup is something that saves your life. You have Dropbox/One Drive/Google Drive/Mega to save some of them. I do not sync mega and transfer things manually, just to be sure that the sync utility won't erase my data. I also use other local backup things as a home NAS for scripted backup and some external drives for manual backup. I have the same data on at least 3 different places. Yes, it's overkill for a home setup, maybe I´m a little paranoid, but since the Great 2003 Disaster here at home...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, no. It does not. All your user data is stored under your user profile at `C:\Users`

But it is *[trivial](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-move-your-default-data-folders-to-a-different-drive/)* to move your `My Documents` and other folders to another drive, and most programs easily allow you to change install locations.

Moving the `Users` directory or profile directories under it is tricky though.

But this is the same as Linux, Linux can use a single partition and end up with programs and user data on the same drive as well, it all depends on how you set up the machine to begin with and how configurable the installer is.

Comment: Except for the time in October 2018 where the Windows 10 update deleted everyone’s files that were in relocated My Documents folders. I lost 2 years’ worth of files and all I got from Microsoft was a $400 cheque.

Comment: @Dai I'm not saying that you are the one to blame, Microsoft surely is. But... backup is something that saves your life. You have Dropbox/One Drive/Google Drive/Mega to save some of them. I do not sync mega and transfer things manually, just to be sure that the sync utility won't erase my data. I also use other local backup things as a home NAS for scripted backup and some external drives for manual backup. I have the same data on at least 3 different places. Yes, it's overkill for a home setup, maybe I´m a little paranoid, but since the Great 2003 Disaster here at home...

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, but you can set it that way, though it requires a bit of gymnastics. You can set paths for your user folder on a different partition if you like (your Documents, Downloads, etc.); see [How to Move Users Folder to another Location in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html)

As I said, it takes some preparation and a little expertise.

Comment: Plus, first, you have to create a new partition on your hard drive or SSD...